# Post to json server issues

Tags: json, angular, angular2-forms

I'm still new at this, but I'm trying to post my own data to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users for learning purposes. At the bottom of the page it says to use `npm install -g json-server` so I ran that command in my project and I tried posting the data to the web url above and I also tried posting it to a static json file thinking it might host the file somehow with the npm install -g json-server command, but I get that the json file is not found when using the local file and if I try posting to the url above, then it shows a post going through in console log, but my table with the users never update. Can anyone tell me how to get this working so I can see my POST data?

user.service.ts

```
      import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {User} from './user';
@Injectable()
export class UserService{
constructor(private _http:Http){


}
getUsers(){
return this._http.get('http://localhost:4200/users')
.map(res=>res.json());

}
addUser(post){

return this._http.post('http://localhost:4200/users', post)
.map(res=> res.json());



}
}
```

form.component.ts

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../users.service';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]

})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit{
  private user;

  private _users;
  constructor(
    private _userService:UserService


  ){


  }

userForm = new FormGroup({
name: new FormControl(),
username: new FormControl(),
email: new FormControl(),
address: new FormGroup({
  street: new FormControl(),
  suite: new FormControl(),
  city: new FormControl(),
  postalcode: new FormControl()

})

});
onSubmit(){
this._userService.addUser(this.userForm.value)
.subscribe(res => {
this.user = res;
console.log(res);

})

}

}
```

Comment: Did you start the server? Also, your URLs still seem to be pointing to the online version instead of your own local.

Comment: I've tried pointing it to both. I posted the above code to point to online, but I also tried point it to app/users.json, which is the local file, but get the message that it's not found. It's the same path as the GET request so I know the path is correct. I updated code above to reflect local json file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to point to app/users.json now that you have the server running. Per [documentation](https://github.com/typicode/json-server), you can just POST to `http://localhost:3000/users`.

Comment: I updated the code above to reflect your suggestion, but it's now not pulling any json data in GET and users.json is in app directory. Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: You may want to check if everything is OK with your server, it's probably returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed that for public service (what is reasonable)

> Note: the resource will not be really created on the server but it
>   will be faked as if.

since you already install it locally, just run:

$jsonplaceholder

after replace your URLs hostname in Angular to **http://localhost:3000**

Comment: I ran the  npm install -g json-server command (Is that what you mean by run jsonplaceholder?) it's now not pulling any json data in GET and users.json is in app directory. Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position

Comment: sorry, I thought you ran (npm install -g jsonplaceholder) as it written in the docs, after you should be able to use (jsonplaceholder) as a command like (gulp or any other npm libs installed globally), json-server is a lib that used by jsonplaceholder